# Google sheets, block data entry if…

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a simple google sheet, with Date, Client ID, Name, etc.

What I would like to do is block any kind of data entry IF the first letter of the Name is NOT UPPERCASE.

I know this might sound a bit silly, but the person entering data just won’t do as I ask, and enters Name's inconsistently. So I want it to be blocked and force him to go back, correct the first letter uppercase, and the be able to enter data.

Another option could be a pop up message that warns that the name has been entered incorrectly? Anything like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create data validation rule for column with formula:

```
=EXACT(LEFT(A:A,1),UPPER(LEFT(A:A,1)))
```

change `A:A` to column reference with names

[image]